# I want to open a PDF file within the application in titanium studio

Tags: titanium

I have URL of PDF file and want to open within the application so that i can navigate back to application. I don't want to go to browser. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

iOS:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.DocumentViewer

Android
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/72361/open-pdf-file-on-android

Or you could try and show it in a webview:

```
var pdfViewer = Ti.UI.createWebView({
  url: "url.pdf",
  width:1000, 
  height:1000  
});
```